# platform.js or api.js? google api

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-api, google-api-js-client

Trying to understand how I should go about referencing the google apis for a static page web app. I am confused.

1. I am unsure where the complete documentation is as I have stumbled upon a few broken links in this repository already
2. These tutorial reference 2 different urls yet seem to be related to this [repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client)

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initparams

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
```

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

```html
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
```

What are the differences? what url should one use? does it matter?
Should one rather use the node client rather than web and compile it?

Comment: also asked on https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/658

Comment: The Quickstart example is ready to use, have you tried it?

Comment: @Jescanellas I have seen the quickstart project already, I am specifically asking about the referenced libraries, both seem to have commonalities yet they're different somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/658#issuecomment-692839901

sergentj commented

> The functionality in platform.js is a superset of the functionality in api.js.
> The documentation for those APIs is correct. If you are using both the sheets APIs and the sign-in API, platform.js will suffice, you needn't load both.
> You are correct that this is poorly documented, and we're aware that's a problem.
> Closing this since it is not going to be useful to track work on improving documentation (which is a much larger issue) here.

Answer (score 2):

Pro tip. Don't use the JS API library. It's more trouble than it's worth. The API is a well formed REST API, so it's easy to consume with any http library such as Axios, or even `fetch`.

Comment: Is it common to do oauth authentication like that? do you have any clue about similar api's such as https://developers.google.com/picker/docs ?

Comment: I do my OAUth by hand. I find it much easier to understand the undocumented edge cases. I've never used the picker, sorry.

Comment: How are you doing OAuth via fetch client-side? Are you opening your own windows in the browser, or are you doing it in the backend and sending the access token to the client afterward and using fetch client-side?

Comment: @AndrewLi I use a hidden iframe